# Reading NFC tags in the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, nfc

As I was working on an E-wallet system, my boss assigned me a job to allow our agents to be able to top-up the clients' wallets by reading their NFC cards. The agents are using a web browser client to browse their CMS part of the System, I made that myself.
Is it possible to read NFC through the web browser?

I thought that wouldn't be possible by writing a JavaScript code on an HTML page, but I imagine that this could be done by making a browser extension. However, I'm not sure if that's the way to go. and what would be the next.

Comment: the NFCs are stuck on a plastic card, the client has to go to an agency where he can pay actual money in order to top up his account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes possible depending on a lot of factors via https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/ but very limited support in terms of browser supported (only some Android web browsers). see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_NFC_API

You are also limited currently to Ndef message format as well as well as some other security limitations, which is probably not used by your NFC cards

Comment: The computer doesn't support NFC, but what's going to happen is that we'll plug an NFC reader into the computer via USB (an external device), so how this API would integrate its features in this case?

Comment: Is there a browser extension that can do that? It just needs to read the NFC card to fill the inputs on the web page

Comment: There are so many different USB Nfc readers that it's probably not really possible to support them via Web NFC but you might be able to interface to a specific USB reader via Web USB (https://web.dev/usb/) and send the reader the right USB commands to read NFC Tags